# CSS animations extremely slow, laggy, and horrible on iOS but fine on desktop

Tags: javascript, css, ios, iphone, mobile

I'm making a fairly simple website, with a couple fairly simple CSS animations. For instance, I have a like button on my site, where people can like comments. When people click the like button, the "heart" transforms itself and scales 2x, and has a smooth transition.

Everything works perfectly fine on desktop on Chrome and Firefox, but when I try it on iOS (on my iPhone 15 Pro Max), it's extremely slow, laggy and unusable.

I also have a submit button with some fancy CSS keyframes that makes little stars move inside the submit button to make it beautiful, and while the animations aren't lagging for this button, the stars on iOS are completely getting out of the container and overflowing over other elements on iOS, while on desktop everything is absolutely fine.

Super frustrating!

I asked chatgpt to help me make webkit queries for iOS, tried a couple things on Google but nothing worked. I honestly believe what chatgpt gave me was utter complete nonsense, which is why I'm coming here for help.

```css
.btn {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 13rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 3rem;
    background-size: 300% 300%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: 0.5s;
    animation: gradient_301 5s ease infinite;
    border: double 4px transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#212121, #212121),  linear-gradient(137.48deg, #ffdb3b 10%,#FE53BB 45%, #8F51EA 67%, #0044ff 87%);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  }

  #container-stars {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
    border-radius: 5rem;
  }

  strong {
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: 'Oooh Baby', cursive;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px white;
  }

  #glow {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 12rem;
  }

  .circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    filter: blur(2rem);
    animation: pulse_3011 4s infinite;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .circle:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: rgba(254, 83, 186, 0.636);
  }

  .circle:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: rgba(142, 81, 234, 0.704);
  }

  .btn:hover #container-stars {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #212121;
  }

  .btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .btn:active {
    border: double 4px #FE53BB;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    transition: 0.1s;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    animation: none;

  }

  .btn:active .circle {
    background: #FE53BB;
  }

  #stars {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    width: 200rem;
    height: 200rem;
  }

  #stars::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10rem;
    left: -100rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: animStarRotate 90s linear infinite;
  }

  #stars::after {
    background-image: radial-gradient(#ffffff 1px, transparent 1%);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
  }

  #stars::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50%;
    width: 170%;
    height: 500%;
    animation: animStar 60s linear infinite;
  }

  #stars::before {
    background-image: radial-gradient(#ffffff 1px, transparent 1%);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  @keyframes animStar {
    from {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }

    to {
      transform: translateY(-135rem);
    }
  }

  @keyframes animStarRotate {
    from {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    to {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
  }

  @keyframes gradient_301 {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%;
    }

    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
  }

  @keyframes pulse_3011 {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0.75);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }

    70% {
      transform: scale(1);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
      transform: scale(0.75);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
  }





.heart {

    width: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    transition: 0.4s;

}



.heart:hover {
    transition: 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.5);

}

.heart:active {
    transition: 0.3s;
    transform: scale(3.7);
    opacity: 0.1;

}
```

```html
  <button class="btn" type="button">
        <strong>Submit</strong>
        <div id="container-stars">
          <div id="stars"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="glow">
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
      </button>


<img src="https://images.emojiterra.com/google/noto-emoji/unicode-15/color/512px/2764.png" class="heart">
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a working [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285) so we can test your code on our various devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this slowness. It's the noto-emoji font. If you do not use it, your website should work fine.

I am highly suspecting that you are using this font, since you have linked this image from noto here:

https://images.emojiterra.com/google/noto-emoji/unicode-15/color/512px/2764.png

But if you are not using it, then let me know.

If you NEED to use noto emoji, I did not find a solution yet. But you can see more here:

[Google Noto Color Font Makes App Extremely Slow on Safari Webkit (IOS/MacOS) but not MacOS Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78008226/google-noto-color-font-makes-app-extremely-slow-on-safari-webkit-ios-macos-but)