# Google Noto Color Font Makes App Extremely Slow on Safari Webkit (IOS/MacOS) but not MacOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, ios, macos, safari

I think this is a bug in Safari/Webkit, as I do not see this issue in Chrome/Firefox.

#### Minimum reproducible example:

On this website the error occurs:

https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji

#### More info:

On Safari, the website for noto color shows the IOS emojis for a few seconds for me, before actually rendering the google emojis:
https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji. But on my app, this is not the behaviour. In my app, the app freezes before displaying the correct emojis. But then when I go onto the glyphs tab, the app even freezes on the google fonts website, in a similar way:
https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji/glyphs

Since I tested this on Firefox too, which afaik does not use chromium, and it worked fluidly there, I thus think this is a Safari Bug/Issue.

related to, but I made it a more concrete question:
[CSS animations extremely slow, laggy, and horrible on iOS but fine on desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77313071/css-animations-extremely-slow-laggy-and-horrible-on-ios-but-fine-on-desktop)

I have just made sure every single emoji that is in my app is displaying with the noto color font. But now it always freezes when I navigate to a view that uses noto color emoji.

Instead of linking a local file, I have tried using the embed approach to include the emojis. Same result. With both the `<link>` and `import` syntax.

I am also considering this approach, as linked on the IOS tab of the noto color font website:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app
maybe this fixes the slowness but I am not sure if it could even do this. I you know whether this could indeed help, then lmk. My app is a CapacitorJS App. So idk how one would do that with Capacitor. Maybe someone can tell me how?

The NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf as downloaded from here:
https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji
is 24MB. I think the slowness might be due to this big size. And maybe it does not appear on chrome, since

Maybe there is some way of making this "preloading" happen once and for all for the app, on Safari? Not make my screen freeze every time?

I have also tried using the twemoji font, for which this did not happen on Safari. But I prefer the Noto Color font by a lot. However using twemoji with a generated subset as explained below would be a last resort for me. If really noone knows an answer, then maybe someone can provide an answer to how to generate this subset for either twemoji or Noto.

The eigth comment here lists an url with a woff2 file for twemoji:
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40766658
I downloaded this file an linked in my app and the app ran smooth on Safari. But the file size was also only 78KB, as it was somehow compressed as discussed here:
https://github.com/talkjs/country-flag-emoji-polyfill

"This is important, because Twemoji Mozilla is 1.5MB, which is a pretty huge hit on your app perfomance. The subset is only 78kb, which is much better."

Maybe someone could provide a guide on how to create subset font files? I would not need all of the emojis from the noto font. Not much more than are included in the 78Kb twemoji flag woff2. I tried following the guide in the github link above but I could not manage to create my own custom font

#### Minumum Reproducible Example from/for post-discussion in the comments below. This works in chrome but in Safari the emojis are invisible:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  ⚡️❌✅
</body>
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Noto Color Emoji';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('./NotoColorEmoji-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Noto Color Emoji', sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</html>
```

I used this url to generate the file:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Color+Emoji&text=⌨️⚡️❌✅⭐️️❓️️️️
```

Tested on:

- iPhone 13 Pro, IOS 17.2.1
- iPad Pro 10.5 inch, IOS 17.2
- Mac Apple M2 Pro, Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71)
- Safari, Google Chrome, Firefox. If u need the versions lmk.

Comment: Please note that an MCVE is the code required to reproduce the problem. It is **not** a wall of text *describing* the problem.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not make it clear through formatting, but this website is the minumum reproducible example:

https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji

Comment: Testing on a Wi-Fi linked iOS iPad I see hardly any pause before the font is visible. Are you sure it isn’t just a slow link on your phones?

Comment: As explained, it happens when I download & reference the local .ttf file as well. My app is primarily offline actually. Did you tes the google fonts website on safari? Especially switching from the first google fonts link into the glyphs tab, where all emoji get shown? The error is not a "pause" before the font is "visible". But it's that my screen freezes. And the rendering just blacks out when I scroll too.

Comment: Have you tried to subset the font with the `text` query parameter? `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Color+Emoji&text=✌%EF%B8%8F` this will drastically reduce the filesize. Besides you get the more compact woff2 version - open the returned css and download the font file from the src property url.

Comment: @herrstrietzel did not expect such a helpful answer. I was trying forever to generate the woff2! works on chrome, -95% size. HOWEVER: this way, the emojis do not display at all on Safari unfortunately. I included a minumum reproducible example at the bottom of my initial question

Comment: Might be related to safari's support for some colrv color formats (they removed it between safari 15.9 - 16.1) - it's quite confusing. Please try to load thie subset url as a link element. This way safari should switch to a suitable alternative color format. But I'm afraid there is currently no bullet-proof solution available. You may also try other versions from the [github repository](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts)

Comment: @herrstrietzel I tried adding the generated stylesheet as a link-element with url. But then it only displayed the default apple 3D emojis, which do not fit my color 2D cartoon ui design unfortunately. But I want to reiterate, the twemoji font did not have this loading bug on Safari! Is it somehow possible to create such a subset as you suggested, but with the twitter twemojis? This would be a solution to the whole problem, since twemojis are supported well on safari.

Comment: This .woff2 file of twemoji from the #8 comment somehow worked perfect for me:
https%3A//issues.chromium.org/issues/40766658

Do you know how to generate it, with a slightly larger subset as noted above @herrstrietzel ?